Код получает значение и останавливается на условии telethon
Форумчане! Во время разработки бота, я столкнулся с такой проблемой - бот получает значение, доходит до условия и на нём и останавливается. Использую python и telethon.
Вот код -
async def getuser(event):
    user_id = event.sender_id
    await client.send_message(user_id, f"Теперь введите ID нарушителя в таком формате 'ID: 0000'")
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=user_id))
    async def handle_message(event):
        global selected_reason, selectID, selectLINK, pr, tehh
        user_id = event.sender.id
        username = event.sender.username
        text = event.text
        link = text.strip("")  # Убираем лишние пробелы по краям
        soo = text
        global selectID
        if "ID:" in soo[0]:
            selectID = soo[1]
            await event.respond(f"ID: {selectID}\nуспешно выбран теперь укажи ссылку на нарушение если она есть в формате 'LINK: https://t.me/durov/2000, если ссылки нету напиши 'LINK: no' ")
            if selectID != None:
                if soo[1] == "no":
                    selectLINK = None
                else:
                    selectLINK = soo[1]
                await event.respond(f"ID: {selectID}\nLINK: {selectLINK}\nЕсли вы уверены в данных, и хотите запустить снос напишите 'ss' ")
            if selectID != None and pr != None:
                await event.respond('Отправка жалобы началась...')
                await startmailattack(event)
            else:
                await event.respond(f"Данные неверные начните заново!")
        if 'https://t.me/' not in link:
            return  # Просто игнорируем сообщение, если нет корректной ссылки
        if not selected_reason:
            await event.respond("❌ Вы не выбрали причину жалобы. Пожалуйста, выберите одну из причин через кнопки.")
            return
    # Отправка жалобы с выбранной причиной
        await event.respond('Отправка жалобы началась...')
        successful_reports, failed_reports = await report_message(link)
        response_text = f'```Уважаемый @{username} ваши жалобы отправлены.\n\nВаш таргет {link}\nУспешных запросов {successful_reports}\nНеуспешных запросов {failed_reports}/{successful_reports}```'
        await event.respond(response_text)
        log_text = f"Log in\n\nАкаунтов в боте 95\nПользователь: @{username}\nID {user_id}\nЖалоб: {successful_reports}\nНеуспешно 0\n⚙ FloddError {failed_reports}\n\nТаргет: {link}"
        await client.send_message(log_chat_id, log_text)

    # Очищаем выбранную причину для следующей жалобы
        selected_reason = None

Если нужен полный код - вот ссылка

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
